# Tutorial on how to merge Navigation drawer into Google map

Tags: android

Any tutorial that can show how to merge a particular Navigation drawer into Google Map v2.

Comment: What have you searched so far? Post your work first

Comment: Here is the tutorial of navigation drawer i want to make http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/  i want to merge it with the google map v2. here is the link http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/  is there any possible way to merge this two?

Comment: find tutorial in Google!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all this Google Map has nothing to do with the Navigation Drawer.Both are independent.

You just have to create Activity/Fragment which has navigation drawer and Add SupportMapFragment for displaying your map and Load this fragment after completion of loading of Navigation drawer items.

For creating Navigation drawer Custom And simple :

http://www.recursiverobot.com/post/59404388046/implementing-the-new-navigation-drawer-in-android

http://www.tutecentral.com/android-custom-navigation-drawer/

Here are another links

http://geck1.blogspot.in/2014/05/google-map-in-navigation-drawer-fragment.html

[Android Drawer Example, how to implement Google Map Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23069410/android-drawer-example-how-to-implement-google-map-fragment)

from which may be you can find some workaround.