# Android GPS location finding

Tags: android-studio, android-location

Iv'e been trying to implement an activity that has a map and can use a button to focus and put a marker on your current location. the problem is most of the time i get a really slow (if any) location data, and while iv'e seen apps do the same in 1-2 seconds, mine takes 20 secs at least to get data if it even gets data. 
how do i speed it up? what am i doing wrong? (if it helps i think i might have used extra unnecessary functions and implemented extra stuff including importing extra stuff the is unnedeed):

here's my code:

MapsActivity.java

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.Toolbar;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

/**
 * AppCompatActivity extends FragmentActivity and allows me to have a menu over the map!
 */
public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback {

    /**
     * THE Map is a FRAGMENT! i must treat it as such and therefore i need something to hold this
     * fragment, another activity will be the Main activity and will hold the map's fragment!
     */

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    Marker marker; // i use this so i can erase it later.

    private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSION_CODE = 1;
    /**
     * This array is holding int values for the many different map types googleMaps
     * offers. the mapType value is now set to 1 for normal and can be changed in an instance.
     */
    private final int[] mapTypes = {GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NONE, GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL
            , GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN, GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE, GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID};
    private int mapType = 1;

    public static final String TAG = MapsActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private Button mGpsLocateButton;
    private Button mAddressLocateButton;
    private TextView mAddressTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);

        /**
         * Setting up a location manager to get location feed from gps or data.
         */
        //mLocationManager = (LocationManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        final LocationFinder mLocationFinder = LocationFinder.getLocationFinder(this);

        /**
         * This is the TextView that shows the local area and street, next up we find the location
         * by string and set the view to show it! we set it on start to show the address of
         * the Central Station in beer sheva. later it will show local address.
         */

        mAddressTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.street_text_view);
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
        LatLng centralStationBS = new LatLng(31.243077, 34.796961);
        String address = findAddress(centralStationBS,geocoder);

        mAddressTextView.setText(address);

        mGpsLocateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.gps_locate_button);
        mGpsLocateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mLocationFinder.startLocationListening();
                Location loc = mLocationFinder.getBestKnownLocation();
                /**
                 * the counter will allow the program to try to acquire position
                 */
                int count = 0;
                while (loc == null && count < 10) {
                    synchronized (this) {
                        try {
                            this.wait(500);
                            count++;
                            loc = mLocationFinder.getBestKnownLocation();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
                /**
                 * if we still got no location we prompt the user to try turning GPS on.
                 * will change later!!!
                 */
                if (loc == null) {
                    int noLocation = R.string.cannot_get_location_toast;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), noLocation, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    mAddressTextView.setText("No address found, Turn GPS on.");
                }
                if (loc != null) {
                    //marker.remove();
                    LatLng currentLoc = new LatLng(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude());
                    //marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(currentLoc).title("You Are Here!").draggable(true));
                    marker.setPosition(currentLoc);
                    marker.setTitle("You Are Here!");
                    marker.setDraggable(true);
                    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(currentLoc));
                    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(17));
                    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(),Locale.getDefault());
                    String address = findAddress(currentLoc,geocoder);
                    mAddressTextView.setText(address);
                }
            }
        });

        mAddressLocateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.address_locate_button);
        mAddressLocateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });


    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);
        // Add a marker in weWork and move the camera
        LatLng weWork = new LatLng(31.264089, 34.812974);
        LatLng centralStationBS = new LatLng(31.243077, 34.796961);
        //i set the marker to draggable, might not be necessery.
        marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(centralStationBS).title("BS Central Station").draggable(true));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(centralStationBS));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(17));
        /**
         * This should check if we have permission and if not it will ask from the user.

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_PERMISSION_CODE);
        }*/

    }

    /**
     * overriding on resume since we might disconnect and the client needs
     * to be connected again.
     * Reminder:
     * Activity LifeCycle: onResume() comes directly after onCreate() so we
     * connect on the beginning.
     */
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    /**
     * overriding on pause since we might want to disconnect when pausing the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        /**  if(requestCode == REQUEST_PERMISSION_CODE){
         if(grantResults.length>0) {
         loc.setPermissionGranted(grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[1]== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
         }
         }*/
    }

    public String findAddress(LatLng location, Geocoder geocoder) {
        String address;
        try {
            List<Address> addressList = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.latitude, location.longitude, 1); //the 1 stands for max results.
            if (addressList != null) {
                Address returnedAddress = addressList.get(0);
                StringBuilder returnedAddressAsString = new StringBuilder();
                for (int i = 0; i < returnedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                    returnedAddressAsString.append(returnedAddress.getAddressLine(i)).append("");
                }
                address = returnedAddressAsString.toString();
            } else {
                address = "No address found";
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            address = "No address found";
        }
        return address;
    }
}
```

LocationFinder.java:

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.util.Log;

/**
 * Here we will use the methods shown in https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html
 * there is a different, maybe easier approach to it in https://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html
 * GIANT NOTE TO SELF: THIS METHOD IS NOT SO ACCURATE, I NEED TO ENHANCE ACCURACY OR CHANGE METHOD TO WHATEVER
 * GOOGLE API MEANT!(the easier method).
 * Created by Snirkd on 6/16/2016.
 */
public class LocationFinder {
    private static LocationFinder mLocationFinder;
    private LocationManager mLocationManager;
    private Context mAppContext;
    private static final int TEN_SECS = 1000 * 10;
    private LocationListener mLocationListener;

    private Location lastKnownGPSLocation;
    private Location lastKnownNetworkLocation;
    private Location bestKnownLocation;

    private boolean hasNewLocation = false;

    private boolean isGPSon;
    private boolean isNetworkOn;

    private boolean requestedUpdates = false;

    private LocationFinder(Context appContext) {
        mAppContext = appContext;
        //acquire a reference to the system location manager
        mLocationManager = (LocationManager) mAppContext.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        initService();
    }

    public static LocationFinder getLocationFinder(Context context) {
        if (mLocationFinder == null)
            mLocationFinder = new LocationFinder(context);
        return mLocationFinder;
    }

    private void initService() {
        //define a listener that responds to location updates
        mLocationListener = new LocationListener() {

            // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 &&
                        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mAppContext, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return;
                }
                Log.d("LOCATION FINDER","I AM HERERERERE6");
                String provider = location.getProvider();
                if(provider.equals(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
                    if(isBetterLocation(location,lastKnownGPSLocation))
                        lastKnownGPSLocation = location;
                }
                if(provider.equals(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)){
                    if(isBetterLocation(location,lastKnownNetworkLocation))
                        lastKnownNetworkLocation = location;
                }
                boolean isLastbetter = isBetterLocation(lastKnownGPSLocation,lastKnownNetworkLocation);
                if(isLastbetter){
                    boolean betterThanBestKnownLocation = isBetterLocation(lastKnownGPSLocation,bestKnownLocation);
                    if(betterThanBestKnownLocation){
                        bestKnownLocation = lastKnownGPSLocation;
                    }
                }else{
                    boolean betterThanBestKnownLocation = isBetterLocation(lastKnownNetworkLocation,bestKnownLocation);
                    if(betterThanBestKnownLocation){
                        bestKnownLocation = lastKnownNetworkLocation;
                    }
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                if(provider.equals(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
                    isGPSon = true;
                }else{
                    isNetworkOn = true;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                if(provider.equals(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
                    isGPSon = false;
                }else{
                    isNetworkOn = false;
                }
                if(!isGPSon && !isNetworkOn){
                    stopListening();
                }
            }
        };
        /**
         *  Register the listener with the location manager to receive location updates
         * The first parameter in requestLocationUpdates() is the type of location provider
         * to use (in this case, the Network Location Provider for cell tower and Wi-Fi based location).
         * You can control the frequency at which your listener receives updates with the second
         * and third parameter—the second is the minimum time interval between notifications
         * and the third is the minimum change in distance between notifications—setting both
         * to zero requests location notifications as frequently as possible. The last parameter
         * is your LocationListener, which receives callbacks for location updates.
         * To request location updates from the GPS provider, substitute GPS_PROVIDER for NETWORK_PROVIDER.
         * You can also request location updates from both the GPS and the Network Location Provider by
         * calling requestLocationUpdates() twice—once for NETWORK_PROVIDER and once for GPS_PROVIDER.
         */
    }

    /**
     * Determines whether one Location reading is better than the current Location fix
     *
     * @param location            The new Location that you want to evaluate
     * @param currentBestLocation The current Location fix, to which you want to compare the new one
     */
    protected boolean isBetterLocation(Location location, Location currentBestLocation) {
        if (currentBestLocation == null) {
            // A new location is always better than no location
            return true;
        } else if(location == null){
            return false;
        }


        // Check whether the new location fix is newer or older
        long timeDelta = location.getTime() - currentBestLocation.getTime();
        boolean isSignificantlyNewer = timeDelta > TEN_SECS;
        boolean isSignificantlyOlder = timeDelta < -TEN_SECS;
        boolean isNewer = timeDelta > 0;

        // If it's been more than two minutes since the current location, use the new location
        // because the user has likely moved
        if (isSignificantlyNewer) {
            return true;
            // If the new location is more than two minutes older, it must be worse
        } else if (isSignificantlyOlder) {
            return false;
        }

        // Check whether the new location fix is more or less accurate
        int accuracyDelta = (int) (location.getAccuracy() - currentBestLocation.getAccuracy());
        boolean isLessAccurate = accuracyDelta > 0;
        boolean isMoreAccurate = accuracyDelta < 0;
        boolean isSignificantlyLessAccurate = accuracyDelta > 200;

        // Check if the old and new location are from the same provider
        boolean isFromSameProvider = isSameProvider(location.getProvider(),
                currentBestLocation.getProvider());

        // Determine location quality using a combination of timeliness and accuracy
        if (isMoreAccurate) {
            return true;
        } else if (isNewer && !isLessAccurate) {
            return true;
        } else if (isNewer && !isSignificantlyLessAccurate && isFromSameProvider) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Checks whether two providers are the same
     */
    private boolean isSameProvider(String provider1, String provider2) {
        if (provider1 == null) {
            return provider2 == null;
        }
        return provider1.equals(provider2);
    }

    @TargetApi(23)
    public void startLocationListening(){
        if(requestedUpdates ==  true)
            return;

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 &&
                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mAppContext, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000, 10 , mLocationListener);
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 10, mLocationListener);
        requestedUpdates = true;
        Log.d("LOCATION FINDER", "I AM HERERERERE1");
        lastKnownNetworkLocation = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        lastKnownGPSLocation = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        Log.d("LOCATION FINDER","I AM HERERERERE2");
        /**
         * check which is better and assign a new location with it. if non exist
         * then we have no new location as of now and will note it.
         */
        boolean betterLocation = isBetterLocation(lastKnownGPSLocation,lastKnownNetworkLocation);
        if(betterLocation && lastKnownGPSLocation!=null){
            bestKnownLocation = lastKnownGPSLocation;
            hasNewLocation = true;
            Log.d("LOCATION FINDER","I AM HERERERERE3");
        }else if(!betterLocation && lastKnownNetworkLocation!=null){
            bestKnownLocation = lastKnownNetworkLocation;
            hasNewLocation = true;
            Log.d("LOCATION FINDER","I AM HERERERERE4");
        }
        else hasNewLocation = false;
        Log.d("LOCATION FINDER","I AM HERERERERE5");

    }

    @TargetApi(23)
    public void stopListening(){
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 &&
                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mAppContext, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListener);
        requestedUpdates = false;
    }

    public boolean hasNewLocation(){
        return hasNewLocation;
    }

    public Location getBestKnownLocation(){
        return bestKnownLocation;
    }

    public boolean isProviderEnabled(String provider){
        return mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(provider);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what i understand from your question is that you want to display current location in a map when you open the MapActivity. For that you can do the following

```
public class MapActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private static final int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 1;
    public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;

    private GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private Marker mCurrLocationMarker;

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        //stop location updates when Activity is no longer active
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_live_watch);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        checkLocationPermission();

        mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapFragment);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mGoogleMap = googleMap;
        mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        //Initialize Google Play Services
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                buildGoogleApiClient();
                mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            }
        } else {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }    
    }

    public synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getBaseContext())
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Inside onConnection Failed");
        if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception error message : " + e.getMessage());
            }
        } else
            Log.d(TAG, "Location services connection failed with code " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Connection established. Fetching location ..");
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        } else if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Connection Suspended. Couldn't fetch location.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
            mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
        }

        //Place current location marker
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(latLng);
        markerOptions.title("Current Position");
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));

        mCurrLocationMarker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
        mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 15));

        //stop location updates
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        }
    }

    // Check Runtime permissions for Marshmallow and above (API 23+) devices
    public boolean checkLocationPermission() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // Should we show an explanation?
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

                // Show an expanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

                //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);

            } else {
                // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
            }
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                    // contacts-related task you need to do.
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
                            buildGoogleApiClient();
                        }
                        mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                        }
                    } else {
                        // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                        // functionality that depends on this permission.
                        Toast.makeText(this, "permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is runtime permission compliant in case you are supporting API 22+ i.e. pre marshmallow devices only you can remove the runtime permission code.

Comment: I will try this and will return with a result. anyway i need the runtime permission, and after testing this specifically its not what slowing me down. thanks for your help!
btw while at it, if you can tell me how do i put this whole map thing in a fragment as a navigation drawer fragment it would help me greatly!
thanks again :)

Comment: Thats a different question all together . Which is already answered here.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25417991/tutorial-on-how-to-merge-navigation-drawer-into-google-map

Comment: Meanwhile, if this answer helped in solving your issue please accept it as an answer and upvote it. Thanks

Comment: thanks, after checking the code this is almost what i needed. i don't neccessary need to update the location data always. what i need is that when the user clicks the button (in my code) it brings location data once, that is not null, and then shuts down updates. thats why i used get fused api location, which seems to not be so good for my needs. what do you reccomend?

Comment: In that case your question is not clear. And you should atleast have the knowledge to do that after being provided the whole things

Comment: i can agree that its not completly clear, and sure, i can start the update and then just end it when i got new location data, but ive seen somewhere that there are functions that just finds the location once and thats it. so to wrap things up: my location finder object is not necessary, and using the updates to later turn them off will not be a heavier load then just locating once?