# Adding Map Fragments to Navigation Drawer

Tags: android

i have a working navigation drawer app and would like to add Map Fragments to each item in the drawer, currently i can only add one map fragment but i cannot show different markers on drawer item click please help.

Comment: Please share your code. How to create a minimal, complete, and verifiable example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: plz post your code in question.

Comment: did you try this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/25685507/3678308 ?